# Ruby on rails error bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, ssl, https

I'm getting this error and idk what it means

DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

```
  create
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/secrets.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install
```

> DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle Fetching source index from
>   rubygems.org/ Retrying source fetch due to error (2/3):
>   Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureEr ror Could not verify the SSL
>   certificate for rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are experiencing
>   a man-in-the-middle attack, but most like ly your system doesn't have
>   the CA certificates needed for verification. For inf ormation about
>   OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without usi ng
>   SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'. Retrying
>   source fetch due to error (3/3):
>   Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureEr ror Could not verify the SSL
>   certificate for rubygems.org/. There is a chance you are experiencing
>   a man-in-the-middle attack, but most like ly your system doesn't have
>   the CA certificates needed for verification. For inf ormation about
>   OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To connect without usi ng
>   SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'. Could not
>   verify the SSL certificate for rubygems.org/. There is a chance you
>   are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your
>   system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For
>   information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To
>   connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change
>   'https' to 'http'."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution 1

First try running

```
gem update --system
```

In your command prompt. If this does not work try using `solution 2`

## Solution 2

It looks like Bundler is having an issue verifying the SSL certificate of the domain. To fix this go into your `Gemfile` and change

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

to

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
```

Change the *http**s*** to *http*. This should fix this issue.